# How to stop videos in cefsharp

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am making a browser using cefsharp in wpf and i want that my browser won't play videos, so i want to disable video streaming in my browser.i searched all over the google but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: add some of your code - what you already have